# Is it possible to use Oracle Developer Studio on a system with OpenJDK installed?

Tags: java

I'm interested in trying out Oracle Developer Studio on Fedora. Fedora's default Java version  is OpenJDK. If you try to run the installation binary for Developer Studio, it quits with this error relating to OpenJDK:

```
Searching for JVM on the system...
This machine has an open source distribution of java (OpenJDK) installed. OpenJDK is not supported. Please install Oracle JDK to proceed.
To download Java installation bundle (JDK or JRE), visit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

I tried downloading and installing Oracle JDK, but even with Oracle JDK installed it gives me this error. Attempting to uninstall OpenJDK threatens to uninstall an extra 395 packages that seem to depend on it, which I'm unwilling to do. Is there a way to run Oracle Developer Studio and have it use the Oracle JDK I have installed?

Comment: I would really like to know if you were successful. I was able to install Developer Studio 12.6 using Oracle's JDK 15.0.1 by creating a link in lib from jrt-fs.jar to dt.jar, or installation would fail. However, after installation I get "Developer Studio is unable to find a supported version of Java".

Comment: @seba unfortunately no, I was never able to get it installed, sorry. I just wrote it off as Oracle actively checking to see if you had OpenJDK installed and trying everything it could to get you to uninstall it.

Comment: Actually,  after installing as I described many utilities,  like the analyzer, do work.

Comment: @seba After installing Oracle Java 8, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Setup the `PATH` to include the Oracle JDK before /usr/bin, and any other location that might contain java executables.  I recommend using a script to set this and then execute the Developer Studio executable.

It may also be possible via `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Do you have a list of which directories these might be? I tried adding every directory within /usr/java that I thought could be relevant but the installer still gives me that error. I even tried setting up the Oracle JDK with the [alternatives system](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Java#Switching_alternatives) but still had no luck.

Comment: Where did you install the Oracle JDK?

Comment: Initially I installed it to `/usr/java`, which is the default, but when following the directions on the Fedora documentation page I uninstalled that version and installed it to `/usr/local/java`.

Comment: I suspect that the executables would be in `/usr/local/java/bin` then, and that's the directory to add to the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the Java Home directory with the `--javahome` parameter. All I had to do was to install the official Java JRE and then specify the installation directory like this:

```
sudo ./developerstudio.sh --javahome /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8-oracle-x64/
```

Then to execute it you also have to specify the JDK location with the parameter `--jdkhome`. Only version 8 seems to work however.

```
/opt/oracle/developerstudio12.6/bin/devstudio --jdkhome /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_202-amd64/jre/
```